# How to prove that the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,:\, f(x)=0,-1<x<1 \}$ is finite, when $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ has the following properties.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$, which is not constant, satisfies
>   $$|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq n^2(|x|+2)$$
>   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and for any positive integer $n$, then the set
>   $$S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,:\, f(x)=0,-1<x<1 \}$$ 
>   is finite.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

(Hints only)

You could show:

- Given a point $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f^{(n)}(x)\neq 0$ for some $n,$ then $x$ has a neighbourhood where $f$ is non-zero (except for at $x$)
- Given a point $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $n,$ you can apply Taylor's theorem "with remainder" to get an equation for any other value $f(y)$ in terms of some derivative $f^{(n)}(t);$ this lets you use the inequality given to you
- It might help to first solve the easier problem where $|f|$ attains a maximum at some point $y.$ Then later try to get rid of this assumption.

Comment: I understood the first and second proposition, but still don't know the last one. Can't figure it out how that proposition is related to solving this problem

Comment: @user488002: what do you mean by last proposition? You can solve the problem when $|f|$ attains a maximum, but you can't solve the general problem?

Comment: can't reach the last one;|f||f|  attains a maximum at y. Doesn't it mean that f is bounded?

Comment: @user488002: ah, sorry - I didn't mean to suggest that assumption is true in general - I just meant it is easier to deal with that special case, and then try to attack the general case. Note $f$ is bounded, and not identically zero, on some compact interval.

Comment: All points of S is isolated, thus S is closed and bounded, which means that S is compact and thus S has finite elements(as a finite sub cover). correct?

Comment: @user488002: yep, that is also the sort of argument I was thinking of